# Multiple condition in tpl prestashop file

Tags: prestashop

I have this situation
in product page I check the url and condition in this case:
`{$string = $product.url}   {$char = $string|strstr:"incisione-si"} {if !$configuration.is_catalog && $char}`
this run very good, but how can i add a second condition?
example:
"incisione_40-si" or "incisione_20-si"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`{if !$configuration.is_catalog && ($string|strstr:"incisione_20-si" || $string|strstr:"incisione_40-si")}`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "[a-z]" with your custom regex pattern in below (code example):

```
{if preg_match("/[a-z]/", $string)}
    The string contains characters a-z
{else}
    The string does not contain characters a-z
{/if}
```